# Python3.x: access self.xxx variables from other Class without inheritation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Class1 with its self variables and methods, and inside a method I use another method from other class (Class2):

```
import Class2
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.1 = None
        self.2 = None
        ...
    def method1(self):
        do something
    ...
    def methodN(self):
        Class2.method(self):
    ...
```

Inside Class2 method I use the same self variables names (self.1, self.2, etc.) of Class1.

I'm surprise of the fact that, when method of Class2 reaches the end the self variables, that I use within Class2 method, are still present in Class1 object.

If I understood well this is only possibile when Class2 inherits Class1, like:

```
import Class1
class Class2(Class1):
    Class1.__init__(self):
    ...
```

How is it possible?

Thanks to all

EDIT: schwobaseggl, thank you very much for your explanation. Now I have understood the difference between function and method (in some books these words are used like a synonims). So in my case, I don't use a method but a function and I also understood that if I use a self.xxx variable inside Class2 that is not present in the object (instance) of Class1, it will be created for the instance. Is it correct?
So self.1 and self.2 variables of instance of Class1 and self.1 and self.2 variables of function of Class2 are not the same, but function of Class2 overwrites self variables of instance of Class1, correct?
But If I want that a class function uses self variables (I mean a value already set) of another class instance I have to use inheritation, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your naming is not quite right. In Python 3 there are no unbound methods. Assume you have a class `B` like

```
class B(object):
  def x(self):
    self.b = 5
```

then `B.x` is just a function

```
> B.x
<function B.x at 0x7f14dd0f1ae8>
```

only when gaining access to an instance, it becomes a method:

```
> b = B()
> b.x
<bound method B.x of <__main__.B object at 0x7f14dd1102e8>>
```

Thus, when calling `B.x` with a random argument which need not be an instance of `B`, it will just do to it what is defined in the function - if possible:

```
class A(object):
  def x(self):
    B.x(self)
```

Since `B.x` sets an attribute `b` on its argument `self`, of course we would expect any instance of `A` to have such an attribute `b` after passing it to `B.x`:

```
> a = A()
> a.x()
> a.b
5
```

You do not even need to define methods in the class:

```
def x(arg):
  arg.a = 7

class A(object):
  x = x

> a = A()
> A.x
<function x at 0x7f14dd0f1378>
> a.x
<bound method x of <__main__.A object at 0x7f14db39aa90>>
> a.x()
> a.a
7
```